# configuration views

Tags: 7, views

In my body field of view, I want to restrict the text entered by the user to a specific number of lines or size. How can I apply this condition?Is there any way to do this by configure that field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to your view and click on the field you want to restrict the text to max length.
2. Click on the "REWRITE RESULTS" and then tick "Trim this field to a maximum length" checkbox
3. Enter Maximum length of characters you want to display.

[image: View configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) module...

> Maxlength allows you to set maximum length of any field on any form
>   making use of the form API. This includes fields created using the UI.
>   (Example: any text field on a node) In D6 Maxlength allows you to set
>   maximum lengths to the body, title and CCK textfields of any content
>   type (node).
>
> When the maximum length is enforced for a field, while editing content
>   of that type some Java Script will countdown how many characters are
>   left, also if the Javascript is turned off, it falls back to form API
>   validation.